# Can not find IApplicationBuilder for mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In what package can i find 
    Microsoft.AspNet.Http.IApplicationBuilder?

I Can not find package which contains even that namespace: Microsoft.AspNet.Http, but as i can see people were using it.

There's only Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http right now.
What happend?

Comment: Is it under Microsoft.AspNet.Builder?

Answer (score 0):

Add following line into **project.json** in '**dependencies**' section:

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
```

Comment: i create ASP.NET MVC application, not ASP.NET Core. There's no project.json file here

Comment: @JeloneK Please check In asp.net MVC6 rc1